# JavaScript regular expression to match a word with any kind of punctuation at the end

Tags: javascript, regex, match, punctuation

I am trying to translate sentences into Pig-Latin using regular expressions. I need to select the words with any kind of punctuation at the end so that I can handle those cases differently.

For example, in "I think, therefore I am." I need an expression to match "think," and "am."

I have tried various approaches, such as `word.match(/\w+[!?.:;]$/)` with no results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that you might be trying to write an expression, maybe a bit similar to:

```
\w+(?=[!?.:;,])
```

### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/g4TGtI/1/)

```js
const regex = /\w+(?=[!?.:;,])/gm;
const str = `I think, therefore I am.
Je pense; donc je suis!
I don't think: therefore I am not?


`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/g4TGtI/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/g4TGtI/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try searching repeatedly for the pattern `\b\w+[!?.,:;]`:

```js
var re = /\b\w+[!?.,:;]/g;
var s = 'I think, therefore I am.';
var m;

do {
    m = re.exec(s);
    if (m) {
        console.log(m[0]);
    }
} while (m);
```